# $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, nonconstant, with $f(0)=f(1)\implies\exists$ point $x\in[0,1]$ s.t $f'(x)$ is rational

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable non-constant function such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Show that there exists a point $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f'(x)$ is a rational number.

I believe that this fact holds true as a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem and Rolle's Theorem.

As $f$ is differentiable $\implies$ $f$ is continuous over this compact set. This means that $f$ attains a max and a min. Now if either maximum or minimum occurs at a point c in the interior $[,]$, then $′()=0$ (by the interior extremum theroem) which is rational.

but how can I prove that f'(x) is a rational number and it is not equal to 0.
Could anyone give some hint on this?

Comment: When you have a maximum or minimum of a function on a compact set, this does not mean that you have that the derivative has to vanishe at this point. Take for example the function $f: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^2$. The maximum would be 1 for $f(1)=1$. It is a global maximum. Not local.

Comment: Peculiar problem?  Try this elementary variant instead: *Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable and that $a$, $b$, $f(a)$, and $f(b)$ are all rational numbers.  Prove there is a point $a<c<b$ so that $f'(c)$ is also rational.*

Comment: but how to prove f'(c) is not equal to 0

Comment: Rolle's theorem says precisely that the point $c$ provided does satisfy $f'(c)=0$.  Why do you want to prove it is not equal to $0$?  Did your question ask for points where $f'(x)$ is rational but not equal to zero?  If so you forgot to mention it.   Indeed there do exist many other such points if you need them.

Comment: In case you were looking for nonzero points, I went ahead and answered that

Comment: @Steve  *Just to clarify.*  Were you thinking that $0$ is not a rational number?  If so understand why we are confused:  it is standard to consider zero as rational, although if the history had been different we call could have decided on a different definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can just apply the Mean Value Theorem.

It tells you that you have some $\xi\in (0,1)$ with

$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=0$. And $0$ is a rational number.

Comment: but my prove need to prove f'(x) is a rational and could not be 0

Comment: @Steve  If you need to find a point where the derivative is a rational number other than zero you should edit the question and make that clear.  The mean-value theorem (or Rolle's theorem) is not enough to find those points.  This answer is correct for your problem as currently stated.

Answer (score 0):

You get way more than 1 rational point, you get a full countably infinite amount.

Since $f$ is nonconstant and $f(0)=f(1)$, there exists a $c\in  (0,1)$  such that $f(c)\neq f(1)$.  Now by the mean value theorem,  you have some point  $d\in (0,c)$  such that $f'(d)=\frac {f(c)-f(0)} c\neq 0$.   By Rolle's theormm, we have another point $e\in [0,1]$  such that $f'(e)=0$.   Now by the intermediate value property of the derivative,  between $d$ and $e$ $f'$ takes on every value between $0$ and $f'(d)$,  and the rationals are dense in any interval

Comment: The intermediate value property of the derivative — often called Darboux's Theorem — is not well-known.

Comment: Your first sentence here in this answer might be misleading.  While there are only countably many rational values for which the derivative is assumed, there might well be uncountably many points that assume rational values.

Comment: is that means we need to show that derivative is continuous, then there is always a point in the interval is rational?

Comment: @Steve No, the derivative is not always continuous.  However, it DOES always have the intermediate value property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)